# Confluence: Create multiple JIRA issues from table: How can I get more than 256 chars of description?

Tags: jira, confluence

I am using Confluence and I have a table of user stories. To easily create JIRA issues for all of them, I just mark the whole table and select "Create multiple issues from table" after clicking the pop-up JIRA icon. I get to select which table columns are used for title and description, everything works well.

However, once created I saw that the description in JIRA (which would be my user story in Confluence) is cut off at 256 characters. How can I get past this limit? I haven't found anything via Google or JIRA / Confluence help, looks like noone ever uses this feature.

(subquestion: How can I define more fields that are carried over into JIRA? I would like to have the version field in the table for example)

Comment: I am dealing with this exact issue at the moment. From my research this appears to be a limit set in the Jira rest API that pertains to the application links. On the Jira side of the equation I have all my multi-line text fields set to accept an unlimited amount of characters. I am reaching out to Atlassian support and will update if they provide a fix.